# textview is clickable in android html.fromHtml

Tags: android, textview

I have to develop one android example.

Here i have to pass the html string value and set the value on textview.

i have used below code:

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/title1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:text="Title"

        android:layout_below="@+id/youtube_view"

       />
```

In android code:

```
 String fullcontent = in.getStringExtra("FullContent");
       full_content = fullcontent.substring(1);

       lblContent = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.title1);

    lblContent.setText(Html.fromHtml(full_content),TextView.BufferType.SPANNABLE);

    lblContent.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
```

Here i have to run the app which means the textview is clickable...how can i disable the textview clickable...

Comment: android:clickable="false"

Comment: yes i have add these..now also my text is clickable.....

Comment: ummmm u can try setting setenabled(false)